# Django objects are appearing instead of translated string

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, internationalization, translation

I have an issue related to python library "Matplotlib". Actually I am creating line graph and bar chart using this library and adding X-axis and Y-axis title using code

```
yaxis = "Production"

xaxis = "year"

plt.ylabel(yaxis, fontsize=20)

plt.xlabel(xaxis, fontsize=20)![enter image description here][1]
```

But at the same time I want to use language translation i18n also
for this I used

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
yaxis = _("Production")
xaxis = _("year")
plt.ylabel(yaxis, fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel(xaxis, fontsize=20)
```

So it is working fine but in graph inplace of translated term at Y and X-axis, Django objects are comming

[image: Matplotlib_Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Lazy translation - Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#lazy-translation):

> Use the lazy versions of translation functions in
>   django.utils.translation (easily recognizable by the lazy suffix in
>   their names) to **translate strings lazily – when the value is accessed
>   rather than when they’re called.**
>
> These functions store a lazy reference to the string – not the actual
>   translation. The translation itself will be done when the string is
>   used in a string context, such as in template rendering.
>
> ...

---

Replace the following line:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

with [`ugettext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.ugettext) (which will return unicode string):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```